# How to retrieve footnote character index values in word using c# in Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have word document with footnote inserted in it. I want to retrieve the index values of footnote. Example- A footnote has the following content- (1) This is sample. I want to retrieve the footnote value-(1) in c# using interop

Answer (score 0):

The Footnote.Index property returns the index value of a Footnote object.

The .Range.Text property returns the footnote text; the .Reference property returns the Range where the footnote appears in the text (but a non-printing symbol, not the index value).